# What is Fortran 14 output?

Tags: fortran, dxf

I am writing a javascript lexer/parser for DXF files and have come across this from the AutoDesk Drawing Interchange and File Formats document:

> The first line of a group is a group code, which is a positive nonzero
>   integer output in FORTRAN I3--that is, right-justified and blank
>   filled in a three-character field (the exception to this is the
>   four-digit extended entity data group codes, which are output in
>   FORTRAN I4).

This clearly states what FORTRAN 13 output is, but what is FORTRAN 14 output?  A Google search returns absolutely nothing.  It must be similar to FORTRAN 13 in style, but how big is the field?

What is FORTRAN 14?

Comment: Probably I3 and I4 (leading character is a letter, not a digit).  That is a fortran format specification for a formatted integer in  three character or four character width field respectively.

Comment: I see. That makes perfect sense. Alan from IRC provided this [link](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap05/INT-out.html)

Comment: I've edited the question to change 13 and 14 to I4 and I4.

Comment: @TimChild I edited the question back, except of the citation.  Your edited completely changed the meaning of it. It was useful for people with the same confusion as the original asker.

Comment: @VladimirF The author asked 'but what is FORTRAN 14 output?'   This make no sense in the context on FORTRAN output codes.  'FORTRAN I4 output' makes perfect sense as a DXF group code  is an integer.

Comment: @TimChild Yes, the author was confused. Write an answers that clears his confusion. Do not change the fundamental meaning of the question!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation mentions `I4`, not `14`. The Fortran output format  `I4` stands for an integer with width four  characters.